# Image Slide Show using Jquery Not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am doing a simple image slide show using jquery. When i run my code in the latest chrome browser, it's not working: it just displays the first image only. My code is below
.
Html Coding :

```
 <script type ="text/javascript" src ="lib1.js" ></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" src ="Haji.js" ></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Haji1.css"/>
</head>
   <body>
          <div class="bodycontent">
               <img src="IMG/haji2.jpg" alt="image1"/> 
               <img src="IMG/haji1.jpg" alt="image2"/>
               <img src="IMG/haji3.jpg" alt="image3"/>
          </div>
   </body>
```

Css :

```
  .bodycontent{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:500px;
}
.bodycontent img{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 width:100%;
 height:400px;
}
```

Jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(function(){
  $('.bodycontent img:gt(0)').hide();
   setinterval(function(){
    $('.bodycontent  :first-child').fadeOut()
       .next('img').fadeIn()
       .end().appendTo('.bodycontent');},1000);
   });
});
```

Can anyone help me..what's wrong with my code?...

Answer (score 3):

It's not:

```
setinterval
```

but:

```
setInterval
```

case matters!
once that is sorted, it works as expected, fading thru the images.

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YxPBE/1/)